# testing client / server interaction with app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, testing, automated-tests

I am implementing a client / server application based on google app engine. My client is implemented in plain old java. Now I would like to test the communication between app engine and my java client. To make the tests most realistic I would like to launch the actual app engine server with my application. When the app engine is running I would like to execute automated test cases which are based on my client's communication API. So my client should connect to the app engine server and I know whether the client server interaction works fine.

Does anybody know set ups where I can test this kind of client / server communication? Ideally the solution integrates with maven because I use it as build tool. But any non maven hints are welcome too :-)

What I tried until now is app engine's local unit testing:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting.html

But I don't know how to test client / server interaction with local unit testing. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest you test the two side independently during your unit-testing phase.  In other words, test the client and its API calls and make sure everything is well-formed and it processes known good/bad responses correctly.  Then test the server-side to make sure it processes known good/bad requests and responds correctly.

Of course, running some *functional-tests* to test the real interactions is also a good idea.  You'll just need to [start your dev server](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#Running_the_Development_Web_Server) to be able to run the tests, then use your GUI automator of choice to run through some tests.

Comment: i am rather interested in the concrete tooling with maven. do you have any hints?